# Scrapy extracts the data in any order

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, request, scrapy

someone could tell me why scrapy extracts the data in any order. I'm trying to scrapy on this page. The idea is to extract all the data houses from top to bottom, then go to the next page and do the same. (until page 20)

I do not know why I take some houses only and in any order. Thank you

```
from scrapy.item import Field,Item 
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose


class PropietiItem(Item):
titulo=Field()
tipo= Field()

class PropietiCrawler(CrawlSpider):
name= "MiPrimerCrawler"
start_urls= ['https://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/search?c=2&l=1&ob=nd&page=1']
allowed_domains= ['propertyfinder.ae']

rules= (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div/a [@class="pagination__link pagination__link--next"]')),follow=True),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div [@class="card-list__item"]/a [@class="card card--clickable"]')),follow=True,callback= 'parse_items'),
)

def parse_items(self,response):
    item= ItemLoader(PropietiItem(),response)
    item.add_xpath('titulo','/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/h1/text()')
    item.add_xpath('tipo','/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/h2/text()')
    yield item.load_item()
```

Comment: Please, fix the indentation of your code example and remove any code that is not needed to reproduce your issue (e.g. `MapCompose` is imported but it’s not used).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to search for items by html code.

If I had to guess, I would say it's doing it in order of the items it finds in the html code.

It is possible that some items have the html code that you are searching for, while other items are labelled differently.

I would suggest first checking the html code of the missing items. If this does not work, I suggest using Selenium.